# How to serve different react apps in one domain

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, dns, webserver, aws-amplify

I have multiple create-my-react apps in different repositories.

Is there a way that I can serve all of them on the cloud under the same domain? For example `domain.com/app1` and `domain.com/app2`. How would deployment look like for them? Would they all get deployed together or can they be separate?

Ideally probably served on AWS via amplify but I’m open to whatever solution that will work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way its using a subdomain for each app.
`app1.mydomain.com` and `app2.mydomain.com`.

It depends on where you have your DNS, but you will need to create both subdomains pointed to aws s3 hosting or amplify.
Serving in the same domain its possible but can get quite complex as you need some custom rules for the redirects and reloads to work properly. I don't recommend doing that.